# Recursive Function for Pyramid-Scheme

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursive-algorithms

consider a group which has 1 user.
each month, every user can bring another user to join the group.
the user that has been joined for 3 months, should leave the group.
calculate the total membership count, after 30 months.

```
MONTH    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
TOTAL    1    2    4    8    14   26   48   88
```

If I'm right with those numbers, from month 1, the recursive function would be f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3)

Is it correct?
if yes then how to calculate the new memberships and leavings counts?

### UPDATE

I found a solution..., correct?

```
n > 3 | G(n) = G(n-1) + G(n-2) + G(n-3) //total count, remove after month 3

n > 3 | L(n) = L(n-1) + L(n-2) + L(n-3) //sum of people left the group per month

n > 3 | N(n) = T(n-1) //new people per month

n > 3 | T(n) = G(n) - L(n) //total count, remove on month, third

MONTH    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
------------------------------------------
G        2    4    8    14   26   48   88
N        1    2    4    7    13   24   44
L        0    0    1    1    2    4    7
T        2    4    7    13   24   44   81
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're whit numbers but the recursive algorithm is:
($F^0_n:$new members , $F^1_n:$1 month members , $F^2_n:$2 month members , $F^3_n:$3 month members)

> $F^0_n=F^0_{n-1}+F^1_{n-1}+F^2_{n-1}$
>
> $F^1_n=F^0_{n-1}$
>
> $F^2_n=F^1_{n-1}$
>
> $F^3_n=F^2_{n-1}$
>
> $f_n=F^0_{n}+F^1_{n}+F^2_{n}+F^3_{n}$

This equations can reduce to

> $A_n= 2A_n-2B_n$
>
> $B_n=A_{n-4}-B_{n-4}$
>     ($A_n=f_n$)
>     ($B_n=F^3_n$)

Which is easier to solve.

Comment: You might define what $A_n$ and $B_n$ are.  You are correct they are easier to solve.

Comment: please take a look at the update

Comment: @zero.zero.seven: I think these twice can not be true. 1.$N(n)=T(n-1)$ 2.$T(n):=$total.

Comment: @zero.zero.seven : If I understand your mean truly the formula $L(n)=L(n-1)+L(n-2)+L(n-3)$ should change to $L(n)=N(n-3)\quad or\quad N(n-4)$